# Sql query displaying users

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

**I have try this but doesn't work**

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
 function getUser($db) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `user` LIMIT 100';
  foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "id".$row['id'] . "\t";
   echo "Name".$row['name'] . "\t";
  }
 }
?>
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "it doesn't work". Do you have error ? No result ? Exception ?

Comment: result is a blank page

Comment: You aren't calling getUser($db); you're just defining the function.

Comment: @mukunda can you post me a sample how to?

Comment: add getUser($db); before your function line

Comment: @mukunda WOW.... THNX. u really awesome its working properly

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the connection string:

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

You use dbname as localhost ?
It should be  dbname=db;

Thanks